# Como acceder a un método de un fragment A desde una activity o desde otro fragment B - Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-asynctask

Lo que deseo hacer es realizar clic en un botón con el nombre de **agregar** por ejemplo y este llame a una función **addItem** que esta en el fragment **VerticalFragment**, **addItem** a su vez llama a la función **addItem** del adaptador de recyclerView, lo he probado con una función para eliminar desde el evento clic y funciona pero no puedo llamarlo a la función  **addItem** para agregar un ítem a la lista del recyclerView cuando guardo un nuevo registro por ejemplo en el patrón maestro. detalle.

Donde en un fragment A, estaria la lista.
Y en el fragment B estaría el formulario de agregar nuevo registro, que al pulsar el botón guarda el registro (eso ya lo solucione), pero que actualice la lista con el nuevo ítem si es agregado, o elimine si se pulsa en el botón eliminar o realice los cambios si se actualiza un item.

Dejo el código que tengo pero aun falta mucho para lograr lo que deseo:

> **POJO**: *Datos*

```
package com.a01luisrene.comunicacionfragments;

public class Datos {
    private String mTitle;
    private String mSubTitle;

    Datos(String title, String subTitle){
        mTitle = title;
        mSubTitle = subTitle;
    }

    public String getmTitle() {
        return mTitle;
    }

    public void setmTitle(String mTitle) {
        this.mTitle = mTitle;
    }

    public String getmSubTitle() {
        return mSubTitle;
    }

    public void setmSubTitle(String mSubTitle) {
        this.mSubTitle = mSubTitle;
    }
}
```

> **ADAPTADOR**: *RecyclerViewAdapter*

```
package com.a01luisrene.comunicacionfragments;

import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class RecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewAdapter
        .DataObjectHolder> {

    private ArrayList<Datos> mDataset;

    private static RecyclerViewAdapter.MyClickListener sClickListener;

    static class DataObjectHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
            implements View
            .OnClickListener {
        TextView mLabel;
        TextView mDateTime;

        DataObjectHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            mLabel = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.vertical_list_item_title);
            mDateTime = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.vertical_list_item_subtitle);
            itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            sClickListener.onItemClick(getAdapterPosition(), v);
        }
    }

    void setOnItemClickListener(RecyclerViewAdapter.MyClickListener myClickListener) {
        this.sClickListener = myClickListener;
    }

    RecyclerViewAdapter(ArrayList<Datos> myDataset) {
        mDataset = myDataset;
    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerViewAdapter.DataObjectHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent,
                                                                           int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.datos_item, parent, false);

        DataObjectHolder dataObjectHolder = new DataObjectHolder(view);
        return dataObjectHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerViewAdapter.DataObjectHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.mLabel.setText(mDataset.get(position).getmTitle());
        holder.mDateTime.setText(mDataset.get(position).getmSubTitle());
    }

    void addItem(Datos dataObj, int index) {
        mDataset.add(dataObj);
        notifyItemInserted(index);
    }

    void deleteItem(int index) {
        mDataset.remove(index);
        notifyItemRemoved(index);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mDataset.size();
    }

    interface MyClickListener {
        void onItemClick(int position, View v);
    }

}
```

> **FRAGMENT**: *FragmentA*

```
package com.a01luisrene.comunicacionfragments;


import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import java.util.ArrayList;


public class FragmentA extends Fragment implements RecyclerViewAdapter.MyClickListener {

    private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    private RecyclerViewAdapter mAdapter;


    public FragmentA() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    public static FragmentA newInstance() {
        return new FragmentA();
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null) {

        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment

        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_a, container, false);

        mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.fragment_recycler_view);
        mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));

        mAdapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(getDataSet());

        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        mAdapter.setOnItemClickListener(this);

        return view;

    }

    private ArrayList<Datos> getDataSet() {
        ArrayList results = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int index = 0; index < 20; index++) {
            Datos obj = new Datos("Some Primary Text " + index,
                    "Secondary " + index);
            results.add(index, obj);
        }
        return results;
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(final int position, View v) {
        new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
                .setTitle("Eliminar item")
                .setMessage("¿stas seguro de eliminar item?")
                .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        // continue with delete
                        mAdapter.deleteItem(position);
                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.no, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        // do nothing
                    }
                })
                .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
                .show();
    }

        public void addItem() {
            new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
                    .setTitle("Agregar Item")
                    .setMessage("¿Estas seguro de agregar el nuevo item?")
                    .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            // continue with delete
                            actionAdd();
                        }
                    })
                    .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.no, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            // do nothing
                        }
                    })
                    .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
                    .show();
        }

        public void actionAdd() {

            Datos object = new Datos("Some Primary Text " + mAdapter.getItemCount(),
                    "Secondary " + mAdapter.getItemCount());
            mAdapter.addItem(object, mAdapter.getItemCount());

            mRecyclerView.scrollToPosition(mAdapter.getItemCount() - 1);

        }


}
```

> **ACTIVITY**: *MainActivity*

```
package com.a01luisrene.comunicacionfragments;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity  implements View.OnClickListener{

    FragmentA mFragment;
    Button btAgregar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            mFragment = FragmentA.newInstance();
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.content, mFragment)
                    .addToBackStack(null)
                    .commit();
        }

        btAgregar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bt_agregar);
        btAgregar.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()){
            case R.id.bt_agregar:
                mFragment = FragmentA.newInstance();
                mFragment.addItem();
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

> **activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bt_agregar"
        android:text="Agregar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"/>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

> **fragment_a**

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
             xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="match_parent"
             tools:context="com.a01luisrene.comunicacionfragments.FragmentA">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/fragment_recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</FrameLayout>
```

> **datos_item**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
              android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/vertical_list_item_title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/vertical_list_item_subtitle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="16dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: ¿no es factible mover el método addItem() a una clase aparte, para que cualquier fragment pueda utilizarlo?

Comment: donde esta el fragment B?

Comment: Te as asegurado que tu código dentro del método `actionAdd()` funcione correctamente? Porque si funciona, la solución es sencilla.

Comment: Adelante con la solución, me servirá lo se.

Answer (score 2):

Para lograrlo desde un fragment, debes de crear una interfaz dentro de ese fragment y debes implementar esa interfaz en el `MainActivity` y en el método de esa interfaz llamas al método `addItem()` del `FragmentA`.

#### FragmetB

Dentro del FragmentB creamos la interfaz

```
public class FragmentB extends Fragment {

    // Interfaz Actualizar
    public interface Actualizar{

        // Método de la interfaz
        public void actualizarItem();
    }

    // Objeto de la interfaz actualizar, con este objeto llamaremos el 
    // método de la interfaz 
    Actualizar actualizar;

    // Costructor
    public FragmentB(){

    }

    // Instancia
    public static FragmentB newInstance(){
        return new FragmentB();
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_a, container, false);

        Button guardar = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.buttonGuardar);

        guardar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                // Se llama el método de la interfaz Actualizar. Al implementar la
                // interfaz Actualizar en la actividad, este método se sobrescribirá
                // y al presionar el botón guardar de este fragment este método se
                // ejecutara en la actividad.
                actualizar.actualizarItem();
            }
        });

        return view;

    }


    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);

        // Aquí nos aseguramos de que en la actividad se haya implementado la interfaz,
        // si el programador no la implementado se lanza el mensaje de error.
        try {
            comunicacion = (Comunicacion) context;
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException(context.toString() + " Debe implementar la interfaz Actualizar en su Activity");
        }
    }


}
```

#### MainActivity

En el MainActivity implementamos la interfaz creada en el FragmentB

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements FragmetB.Actualizar {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            mFragment = FragmentA.newInstance();
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.content, mFragment)
                    .addToBackStack(null)
                    .commit();
        }
    }

    // Método de la interfaz Actualizar
    @Override
    public void actualizarItem() {

        if (mFragment != null){
            mFragment.addItem();
        }
    }

}
```

Con esto realizado, cada vez que presiones el botón guardar del `FragmentB` se ejecutara en el MainActivity el método `actualizarItem()` de la interfaz `Actualizar` y desde el método `actualizarItem()` llamas el método `addItem()` del `FragmentA`.

---

**Actualización:**

Por lo que veo el problema esta en dentro del metodo onClick() de tu MainActivity, ya que en el estas creando un nuevo fragmento y en ese nuevo fragmento es que estas llamando el metodo addItem() para que agregue un nuevo item a la lista. Para solucionar el problema tienes que llamar el metodo addItem() desde el fragmento que creas en el onCreate(), para que se actualizen los items de la lista de ese fragmento. Para hacerlo solo tienes que llamar el metodo addItem() (en el onClick) si crear una nueva instancia del fragmento.

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()){
        case R.id.bt_agregar:

            if(mFragment != null){
                mFragment.addItem();
            }

            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Excelente mi amigo voy a implementarlo, haber que sucede!

Comment: ok, me dice cualquier cosa, estaré por aquí cerca.

Comment: Amigo David, funciona perfecto, pero tengo un problema que me tiene pensativo es la misma situación pero los fragments, se encuentran en dos actividades, me explico la lista esta en la activity A y el formulario esta en la                     B como hago lo mismo para este caso.

Comment: Bien @Luis Rene Mas Mas si las respuestas le fueron de ayuda, es bueno que muestre su gratitud realizando alguna acción, como puede ser dando un voto, marcándola como aceptada o ambas.

Comment: Así sera amigo David, me puede facilitar la información de la anterior pregunta.

Comment: Seria bueno que publicara una nueva pregunta con todos los detalles.

Comment: Ok, ahora mismo lo hago, espero su visita.